# PCLVisualizer KeyboardEvent detects release but there is none

Tags: c++, keyboard-events, visualizer, pcl

I was following this tutorial on the ICP algorithm implemented in the PCL library:

https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/interactive_icp.html

which works fine, however, if you keep pressing 'space' without releasing it will add too many iterations. So I tried to implement a check for 'space released' before a new iteration.

But the `KeyBoardEvent` does not behave the way I would expect, that is, if a key is pressed, `event.keyDown()` evaluates to 1, if released, to 0.

To demonstrate this, have a look at the following example:

```
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>

void keyboardEventOccurred( const pcl::visualization::KeyboardEvent &event, void *nothing )
{
  std::string action = "";
  if ( event.keyDown())
    action = "down";
  if ( event.keyUp())
    action = "up";

  std::cout << action << '\n';
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer( "Viewer" );
  viewer.registerKeyboardCallback( &keyboardEventOccurred, (void *) nullptr );
  viewer.spin();
}
```

Now if I press and hold 'space' I would expect the output to be 'down' all the time. However, it is

```
down
up
down
up
down
up
down
up
...
```

Why does it detect a 'release' when there is none?

Here is the link to the official PCL Visualizer documentation:
https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html

Comment: What is this pcl? A library? Please share the library website.

Comment: It's the Point Cloud Library, I've added a link the the class documentation.